# Why *this returned from a const member function cannot be used to call other functions in C++?

Tags: c++, constants, this

I got the following code:

```
class Book
{
public:
    void print();
    const Book &Book::get();
};
void Book::print()
{
    cout << "print()" << endl;
}
const Book &Book::get()
{
    cout << "get()" << endl;
    return *this;
}
```

Then I did:

```
Book b;
b.get().print(); // This did not work. Why is that?
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It can call other functions, but not in this case.

You're returning a `const Book &` from `get()`. This is then calling `print()`, which is a non-const function. To fix this, make `print()` const:

```
void print() const;

void Book::print() const
{
    cout << "print()" << endl;
}
```

This const ensures your object's state will not be changed, which complies with the const object you return from `get()`. Note that it can change `mutable` members though, as that's their whole purpose.

Edit:
By the way, the term you're looking for is `method chaining`.

Answer (score 2):

Book::print() is not a const member function and hence cannot be called with the const Book reference returned by Book::get().